# Unexpected error when running PowerShell in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am getting an error when I try to run the PowerShell on my Windows 10 machine. Here is the description:

**Windows PowerShell terminated with the following error:
The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState' threw an exception.**

I checked online if PowerShell can be re-installed, but it seems that's not an option in Windows 10. What can I do to fix this error?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The error you are getting is connected to a known issue, in a PowerShell dll, that was patched in [January 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3124263/cumulative-update-for-windows-10-version-1511-january-12--2016).  If you are getting this error it likely means you are using an unsupported version of Windows 10 (i.e. 1511) considering this particular issue with the dll only applies to 1511

Comment: The problem dll is belongs to `System.Management.Automation`, the fix to this problem, is **to patch your system**.  If you are not running 1511, then supply some information about the dll in question, so I can do more [research](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1638#issuecomment-170664466) otherwise I will be submitting an answer that indicates you should patch your system

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do to fix this error?

According to my research the error you received is a known issue which was patched back in January 2016 with the release of [KB3124263](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3124263/cumulative-update-for-windows-10-version-1511-january-12--2016).  Based on my research the bug report which resulted in a fix was [VS2015 Nuget Console not loading #1638](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1638#issuecomment-170664466).

> The type initializer for
>   **System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState** threw an
>   exception.

The problem is connected to the dll associated with `System.Management.Automation 3.0` and was caused by a stack overflow bug.  You should either install the associated patch and/or upgrade to a support feature update of Windows 10 in order to resolve your problem.

### Sources

- [The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState' threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388394/the-type-initializer-for-system-management-automation-runspaces-initialsessions)